# Could USBport remain open after the process opening it was killed?

Tags: c

I am troubleshooting the following issue:

Step 1: 
A process (e.g., process A) opens a USB port at the beginning as follows:

`int fd = open("/dev/ttyUSB0", O_RDWR);`

Step 2:
Process A then was killed by other process (e.g., process B) WITHOUT  calling:

`close(fd);`

Step 3:
Process A was restarted by process C, which triggered the open USBPort again:

`int fd = open("/dev/ttyUSB0", O_RDWR);`

I wonder if /dev/ttyUSB0 would remain open after step 2 since close function was not called before process A was killed.

Could this cause problems in step 3 if "/dev/ttyUSB0" remains open as the same port was reopened?

Please advise.

Comment: I believe if the parent process dies then any resources it had allocated / opened should be closed automatically.

Comment: so I do not need to close  those opened USB ports before the process was killed?

Comment: I don't know if the rules are any different with /dev/ttyUSB0 but typically no. You don't have to because if the process terminates it releases all its handles. It's like any other file.

Comment: You can't close because you don't have the handle.